# Push mechanism: Auth on webhook endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am curious how auth would work for Push mechanism. It requires an endpoint on the subscriber which has to be accessible over internet so is pubsub client going to validate that message pushed is indeed coming from google? or is that left upto subscribers to implement?

If it is left up-to subscribers what are suggested way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The team is aware that this is not an ideal solution, but for now, the only option is to add a secret token in the push endpoint URL as described at:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/faq#security

You can also periodically rotate the secret token for better security. Of course you need to keep the secret token securely.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, I'd suggest the following:

1. Generate a secret key. Store this secret key on the publisher and on the endpoint.
2. When pushing a message on to the queue, use HMAC-SHA256 with the secret key to create an HMAC of the message data. Add this HMAC value as an attribute of the message (base64 encoded).
3. When receiving a message on the handler, manually create an HMAC of the message data using HMAC-SHA256 with the secret key, and verify that it matches the HMAC in the message attribute.

As long as you keep the secret key... secret, and your message data is unique every time (add a nonce if not), this will guarantee that the message is legit.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the prefix **/_ah/push-handlers/** for the push endpoint URL path. This will allow you to require administrator login by adding `login: admin` in your app.yaml.

Example: **myapp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/myhandler**

From https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/advanced